# Is there a faster way to find primes in lua?

Tags: lua

I am working on Project Euler, and my code is just taking way too long to compute. I am supposed to find the sum of all primes less than 2,000,000  , but my program would take *years* to complete. I would try some different ways to find primes, but the problem is that I only know one way.

Anyways, here is my code:

```
sum=2
flag=0
prime=3
while prime<2000000 do
    for i=2,prime-1 do
        if prime%i==0 then 
            flag=1 
        end
    end
    if flag==0 then 
        print(prime)
        sum=sum+prime
    end
    prime=prime+1
    flag=0
    if prime==2000000 then 
        print(sum) 
    end
end
```

Does anyone know of any more ways to find primes, or even a way to optimize this? I always try to figure coding out myself, but this one is truly stumping me.

Anyways, thanks!

Comment: Eratosthenes will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is based on [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Whenever a prime is found, its multiples are marked as non-prime. Remaining integers are primes.

```
nonprimes={}
max=2000000
sum=2
prime=3
while prime<max do
   if not nonprimes[prime] then
      -- found a prime
      sum = sum + prime
      -- marks multiples of prime
      i=prime*prime
      while i < max do
         nonprimes[i] = true
         i = i + 2*prime
      end
   end
   -- primes cannot be even
   prime = prime + 2
end
print(sum)
```

As an optimization, even numbers are never considered. It reduces array size and number of iterations by 2. This is also why considered multiple of a found prime are (2k+1)*prime.

Your program had some bugs and computing n^2 divisions is very expensive.

Comment: `i=3*prime` should be replaced with `i=prime*prime`

Comment: Right. Multiples below this value have already been processed. Fixed the code, thanks.

Comment: Thanks! I never knew about the Sieve of Eratosthenes, but its method is so simple.